# Delete text once placed in array

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm wondering if it's possible to delete a string as it's placed into and array? this is the code i'm working on:

```
  def footnotes(text)
    file = File.open(text, "r+")
    contents = file.read

    notes = []
    search = contents.scan(/\\f.*?\\f\*/).each do |find|
      notes.push(find)
    end

    result = notes.each do|note| puts "#{note}\n"
    end
    fn = File.open('footnotes.txt', 'w+')
    fn.puts(result)
    fn.close
    file.close
  end
```

I was hoping i'd be able to delete `\\f.*?\\f\*` in the text once it's found and put into an array

Comment: SO you want to delete every string in the array?

Comment: no i need to delete the matched text in the text as it's put into an array. so eg. once "cat" is found in the string "i have a cat" it will then delete the match in the string but keep it in the array, so the result would be array: ["cat"] string: "i have a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`String#gsub!`](http://devdocs.io/ruby/string#method-i-gsub-21) or [`String#sub!`](http://devdocs.io/ruby/string#method-i-sub-21):

```
str = "I have a cat!"
str.gsub! 'cat', ''
#=> "I have a !"
```

`gsub!` will replace ALL occurences in the string, `sub!` only the first one.

Comment: thank you this works really well, but why doesn't `str.gsub('cat', '')` work? i thought it was practically the same thing. although i'm still not sure what "!" does

Comment: `gsub` will perform the substitutions and return a new String, while `gsub!` will do the substitutions on the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way out:

```
array -= %w["my string"]
```

*Let me know if u are looking for something else*

Comment: am i right in assuming this would delete what's already in the array? i don't need to delete anything in the array i just need to delete the text once it's found (see comment above) sorry i don't think i explained very well

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'I have a cat'
array = ['cat', 'mouse']
string.slice!(array[0])
p string #=> "I have a "
```

Comment: hmm this is useful as you can use regex with it but is there a way to delete all occurrences of the search eg in this: `
`string = 'I have a 33cat22'
array = ['cat', 'mouse']
string.slice!(/\d+/)
puts string
#=> "i have a cat22"`
but it doesn't delete "22"